# Is there an error in the following OpenCV source code? (#ifdef without #else)

Tags: c++, opencv, conditional-compilation

This is a part of Otsu binarization algorithm implementation from OpenCV (v4.1.2, /opencv-4.1.2/modules/imgproc/src/thresh.cpp)
The code below computes image histogram `h[N]` (where N = 256 gray values), then do some math. I think there is an error in hist computation part.
There are two versions - simple brute-force loop and unrolled loop version. And brute-force loop run independently of CV_ENABLE_UNROLLED flag.

```
static double
getThreshVal_Otsu_8u( const Mat& _src )
{
    Size size = _src.size();
    int step = (int) _src.step;
    if( _src.isContinuous() )
    {
        size.width *= size.height;
        size.height = 1;
        step = size.width;
    }

#ifdef HAVE_IPP
    unsigned char thresh = 0;
    CV_IPP_RUN_FAST(ipp_getThreshVal_Otsu_8u(_src.ptr(), step, size, thresh), thresh);
#endif

    const int N = 256;
    int i, j, h[N] = {0};
    #if CV_ENABLE_UNROLLED
    int h_unrolled[3][N] = {};
    #endif
    for( i = 0; i < size.height; i++ )
    {
        const uchar* src = _src.ptr() + step*i;
        j = 0;
        #if CV_ENABLE_UNROLLED
        for( ; j <= size.width - 4; j += 4 )
        {
            int v0 = src[j], v1 = src[j+1];
            h[v0]++; h_unrolled[0][v1]++;
            v0 = src[j+2]; v1 = src[j+3];
            h_unrolled[1][v0]++; h_unrolled[2][v1]++;
        }
        #endif
        for( ; j < size.width; j++ ) <-------------------------------- !!!here
            h[src[j]]++;
    }

    double mu = 0, scale = 1./(size.width*size.height);
    for( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        #if CV_ENABLE_UNROLLED
        h[i] += h_unrolled[0][i] + h_unrolled[1][i] + h_unrolled[2][i];
        #endif
        mu += i*(double)h[i];
    }

    mu *= scale;
    double mu1 = 0, q1 = 0;
    double max_sigma = 0, max_val = 0;

    for( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        double p_i, q2, mu2, sigma;

        p_i = h[i]*scale;
        mu1 *= q1;
        q1 += p_i;
        q2 = 1. - q1;

        if( std::min(q1,q2) < FLT_EPSILON || std::max(q1,q2) > 1. - FLT_EPSILON )
            continue;

        mu1 = (mu1 + i*p_i)/q1;
        mu2 = (mu - q1*mu1)/q2;
        sigma = q1*q2*(mu1 - mu2)*(mu1 - mu2);
        if( sigma > max_sigma )
        {
            max_sigma = sigma;
            max_val = i;
        }
    }

    return max_val;
}
```

There must be

```
for( i = 0; i < size.height; i++ )
    {
        const uchar* src = _src.ptr() + step*i;
        j = 0;
        #if CV_ENABLE_UNROLLED
        for( ; j <= size.width - 4; j += 4 )
        {
            int v0 = src[j], v1 = src[j+1];
            h[v0]++; h_unrolled[0][v1]++;
            v0 = src[j+2]; v1 = src[j+3];
            h_unrolled[1][v0]++; h_unrolled[2][v1]++;
        }
        #else
        for( ; j < size.width; j++ ) <-------------------------------- !!!here
            h[src[j]]++;
        #endif
    }
```

Comment: It is for the remaining portion for when `size.width % 4 != 0`, although even if it is there's a nice `- 4` in the `for` condition, so it's always needed.

Comment: Independent from whether it's an actual bug or not, this is better placed at [OpenCV's GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't a bug. Notice that the `j` variable is not reset at the start of each loop. The first loop processes blocks of 4 items (whatever they are) until there are less than 4 left. At that point, j is the index of the next item that needs processing. The second loop processes the remaining items individually.

If `CV_ENABLE_UNROLLED` is not defined, then `j` is 0 (because the first loop doesn't update it) and the second loop processes every item individually.